# Magento 2: Sql query is automatically printing on frontend while getting collection in phtml file

Tags: magento2, collection

I am trying to get data by a specific id in **phtml** file in **Magento 2**.
Here is the code:

```
 $chartid = $this->getData('widgetlist');
 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
 $chart = $objectManager->create('Nfusionsolutions\NfusionWidgets\Model\ResourceModel\Nfusionwidgets\Collection');
 $chart->load($chartid);
 $chart_detail = $chart->getData();
```

I am getting result from this code but it also **prints sql query** in **frontend** like this:

```
 SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `nfusionwidgets_nfusionwidgets` AS `main_table`
```

I found that if I comment **4th line**, sql query does not print but I have to load this by id anyhow.

*Is there any solution to remove sql query from frontend.*

Comment: `$chart = $objectManager->create('Nfusionsolutions\NfusionWidgets\Model\Nfusionwidgets');
 $chart->load($chartid);` try this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for load use this

```
$chart = $objectManager->create('Nfusionsolutions\NfusionWidgets\Mode‌​l\Nfusionwidgets'); 
$chart->load($chartid);
```

For the collection

```
$chart = $objectManager->create('Nfusionsolutions\NfusionWidgets\Model\ResourceModel\Nfusionwidgets\Collection');
$chart->load();
```

Third option `getFirstItem`

```
$chart = $objectManager->create('Nfusionsolutions\NfusionWidgets\Model\ResourceModel\Nfusionwidgets\Collection');
$chart->addFieldToFilter('columnam','value');
$chart->getFirstItem();
```

Comment: Error filtering template: Class Nfusionsolutions\NfusionWidgets\Mode‌​l\Nfusionwidgets does not exist

Comment: I want to use first one load by id but giving above error

Comment: @ArshadHussain there must be model class check for that use that for loading single item. other wise you have to add filter in collection.

Comment: My folder structure: app\code\Nfusionsolutions\NfusionWidgets\Model\ResourceModel\Nfusionwidgets\Collection.php

Comment: @ArshadHussain use third one maybe helpful in you condition

Comment: Third one worked. Thanks. You are very intelligent.

Comment: @ArshadHussain it is always best to use **factory method** http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/113042/which-are-best-method-to-get-collection-in-magento-2